# How to escape quotes in a AWS CLI in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run an AWS CLI command to modify the DefaultActions block of one of my ALB listeners. I do this on my terminal.

```
$ aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'
```

How would I code this in a Jenkins pipeline so the single-quotes and double-quotes in the --default-actions string are preserved? I do this now

```
def defaultActions = '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'
sh """
    aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions \\'$defaultActions\\'
"""
```

But it is interpreted as this, where the double-quotes are removed.

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:803597461034:listener/app/sb-zift-admin-lb/375b68a2c9e7550c/fbb5e9154eb73ab5 --default-Actions '[{Type: redirect, RedirectConfig: {Protocol: HTTPS, Port: 443, Host: #{host}, Query: #{query}, Path: /#{path}, StatusCode: HTTP_301}}]'
```

On a side note, I'm doing this in AWS CLI since I understand that even though the API is available, the option is not available in Cloudformation yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes in `defaultActions` string as well. The `sh` pipeline step performs parameter expansion before passing it to the shell. In your case escaping `"` with double slash like `\\"` should do the trick:

```
def defaultActions = '[{\\"Type\\": \\"redirect\\", \\"RedirectConfig\\": {\\"Protocol\\": \\"HTTPS\\", \\"Port\\": \\"443\\", \\"Host\\": \\"#{host}\\", \\"Query\\": \\"#{query}\\", \\"Path\\": \\"/#{path}\\", \\"StatusCode\\": \\"HTTP_301\\"}}]'
sh """
    aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions \\'${defaultActions}\\'
"""
```

I have run an example with `echo` command instead `aws` and it produced expected result:

```
+ echo elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'
elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'
```

Comment: Thanks. I asked a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846705/why-is-jenkins-flagging-an-error-with-correct-aws-cli-syntax