# Why is Jenkins flagging an error with correct AWS CLI syntax?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

I was having issues with escaping quotes for a shell command in Jenkins pipeline, so I asked in [How to escape quotes in a AWS CLI in a Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843748/how-to-escape-quotes-in-a-aws-cli-in-a-jenkins-pipeline), which was answered and the quotes are now escaped correctly when I run the command.

However I get the following in Jenkins when I execute the following aws elbv2 CLI command in a pipeline

```
+ aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/my-alb/123456789 --default-actions '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'

Error parsing parameter '--default-actions': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'[{"Type":"redirect","RedirectConfig":{"Protocol":"HTTPS","Port":"443","Host":"#{host}","Query":"#{query}","Path":"/#{path}","StatusCode":"HTTP_301"}}]'
```

If I put an "=" sign after --default-actions, like the error message says, I get the same error.

If I copy/paste the command I execute in Jenkins into a terminal, it works!

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3070. It could be due to the use of variable in single quotes `\\'${defaultActions}\\'`. Should it be within single quotes at all ? Maybe you can try using `shorthand syntax` of aws command to see if it works.

Comment: Shorthand syntax without any single or double quotes `aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:listener/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188/f2f7dc8efc522ab2 --default-actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-new-targets/2453ed029918f21f`

Comment: @ben5556 I googled the syntax and that is what I found. Again, if yo enter my AWS CLI command on a terminal, with that syntax, it works. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3481

Comment: @ben5556, also the shorthand syntax from the reference page doesn't even work at all, per the github link I provided in previous command, and from personal experience